# Cleaner way to reference the selector name

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

The code below works, but I suspect there is be a cleaner.

Any alternative to reference the selector names, specially the first differently?

**jQuery**

```
$(".add_one_more").click(function(){            
            var themsg = $(this).parent().attr('id');            
            $('"#'+themsg+'"').stop().fadeOut("slow",function(){                
                $("#entry_area").stop().fadeIn("slow");
            });

            return false;             
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="entry_area">Form Goes Here</div>
<div id="msg0">
    <span style="font-size: 130%; color: green;">One Message</span>
    <a href="" class="add_one_more">Try Again</a>
</div>
<div id="msg1" style="width: 550px;">
    <span style="font-size: 130%; color: red;">Another Message</span>
    <a href="" class="add_one_more">Try Again</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that if your code works, you could post this kind of question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: FWIW, `'"#'+themsg+'"'` would create a string containing leading and trailing quotation marks, i.e. the **content** of the string is `"#someID"`, where it really should be `#someID`.

Comment: @JMax Thanks, I'll do next time, wasn't aware.

Comment: @FelixKling It actually should be "#someID" because it's a selector string.

Comment: It is a selector string, but your code is equivalent to `$('"#someID"')` which is wrong. String concatenation always results in a string, so `$('#'+themsg)` would be correct.

Comment: @FelixKling Understand completely. Now, I'm curious why it didn't work when I tried $('#'+themsg), maybe because I used: $("#"+themsg)

Comment: No, that should not matter, double quotes and single quotes make no difference in JavaScript. I don't know hy it didn't work, it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to select the parent and get its ID.

```
    $(".add_one_more").click(function(){                      
        $(this).parent().stop().fadeOut("slow",function(){                
            $("#entry_area").stop().fadeIn("slow");
        });

        return false;             
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I like quite a bit of what you're doing, but I'll add my thoughts on making your js more resilient to getting pieces moved around.

### JS

```
$("#entry_area, div.message").bind("stop", function(evt){
   $(this).stop().fadeIn("slow");
} );

$(".add_one_more").click(function(evt){   
  $(this).closest("div.message").trigger("stop");
  $("#entry_area").trigger("stop");      
            return false;             
        });
```

### html

```
<div id="entry_area">Form Goes Here</div>
<div id="msg0" class="message">
    <span style="font-size: 130%; color: green;">One Message</span>
    <a href="" class="add_one_more">Try Again</a>
</div>
<div id="msg1" class="message" style="width: 550px;">
    <span style="font-size: 130%; color: red;">Another Message</span>
    <a href="" class="add_one_more">Try Again</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'd say you don't need to store the `id` if you don't re-use it after all, try:

```
$(".add_one_more").click(function(){            
        var $parent = $(this).parent();            
        $parent.stop().fadeOut("slow",function(){                
            $("#entry_area").stop().fadeIn("slow");
        });

        return false;             
    });
```

or even shorter without storing the jquery object in a var ([EDIT] This is exactly what Daniel posted while I was writing this).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The above has syntax errors. Javascript variable names can't have preceding $ sign unless calling a jQuery selector or function.

Comment: @Codex73: That is not true. `$` is valid character in any variable name. It is not at all related to jQuery, apart from the fact that jQuery uses the one letter variable `$` to assign its main function. But it could also just use `j`. jQuery is just a library, it cannot limit or extend the capabilities of JavaScript.

Comment: @Codex73: using the `$` in the name is a way to remember this var refers to a jquery object. Thanks @Felix for correcting

Comment: @JMax Thanks Guys, I appreciate this a lot. My comment should have not implied error but questioned it's answer instead. I will adopt the $ going forward.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var themsg = $(this).parent();
themsg.stop() ...
```